# Installing Munin on Centos 6

Tags: munin, centos6

I've hit problems installing munin on Centos 6. This seems to be a conflict between parts of Perl. I think the version of Perl is newer on Centos 6 (v5.10.1)

When installing munin via yum I get errors relating to perl dependencies as below. I'm not a big enough whiz at yum or rpm to figure out the issue. Munin documentation does not yet talk about installing to Centos 6.0

```
Error: Package: munin-node-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch (/munin-node-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch)
           Requires: perl(Net::SNMP)
Error: Package: munin-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch (/munin-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch)
           Requires: bitstream-vera-fonts
Error: Package: munin-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch (/munin-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch)
           Requires: perl(HTML::Template)
Error: Package: munin-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch (/munin-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch)
           Requires: perl-Net-SNMP
Error: Package: munin-common-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch (/munin-common-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: munin-node-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch (/munin-node-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch)
           Requires: perl(DBI)
Error: Package: munin-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch (/munin-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch)
           Requires: perl(Log::Log4perl)
Error: Package: munin-node-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch (/munin-node-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch)
           Requires: perl(LWP::Simple)
Error: Package: munin-node-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch (/munin-node-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: munin-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch (/munin-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch)
           Requires: perl(RRDs)
Error: Package: munin-node-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch (/munin-node-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch)
           Requires: perl-Net-Server
Error: Package: munin-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch (/munin-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch)
           Requires: perl(Date::Manip)
Error: Package: munin-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch (/munin-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: munin-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch (/munin-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch)
           Requires: perl-Net-Server
Error: Package: munin-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch (/munin-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch)
           Requires: perl(CGI::Fast)
Error: Package: munin-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch (/munin-1.4.2-0.rpl1.el5.noarch)
           Requires: perl(Time::HiRes)
```

Comment: What repository are you installing munin from? For CentOS 6, munin version 1.4.7 is in EPEL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential problem is that you're trying to install EPEL5 packages on CentOS6. You should get your packages from EPEL6.

You can find the latest repo rpm at: http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm

Once it starts installing and looking for the correct packages, things should get easier.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the required Perl modules *before* installing munin.

Comment: any idea how you do that? like via CPAN or something, or can I do it with yum

Comment: You are free to chose your option. Both is possible.

Answer (score 0):

RPM package names that have '.el5' are for Centos5 or RHEL5. Instead of trying to install munin-1.4.2-0.rpl1.**el5**.noarch, which is meant for Centos5 or RHEL5, you need to install the Centos6 version of munin.

Answer (score -2):

You could try using `--skip-broken` to work around the problem.

You could try running: `rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`